# Gradle - Missing sub-project jar in parent-project war for eclipse deployment

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, eclipse-wtp

I have a gradle multiple projects like this:

```
root
  --core
  --web
```

When I include these projects in my eclipse, the war project hasn't jars of core in the classpath, so I can't deploy my war in a server.

If I deploy the generated war from web/build/libs to my tomcat server, all works fine.

But if I deploy from  eclipse the I get class not found error for the class from core project.

build.gradle from web:

```
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
apply plugin: 'war'

dependencies {
    compile project(':core')
    //runtime project(':core')
    providedCompile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. The solution is to include

```
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
```

not just in web, but in every sub-project.

Comment: It solved my problem! Thanks a lot! But it would be fine if you explain why it is required. Just for knowledge sharing.. ;)

Comment: I found that solution by trial & error :) Sad to hear that that answer is still relevant five years later.